# Does qt has a platform-independent newline?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, newline

I'm developing an application on Windows that I may eventually port do Linux. I need to build a string with new lines, so instead of hard-code this newline `\r\n` in a string I'd like a platform-independent version. Does Qt has this or I should define it on my own with macros?

Comment: If you open a `QFile` with `QIODevice::Text` flag, it will convert any line breaks to platform-dependent characters on write.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: I'm aware about this but I'm not using a `QFile`

Comment: QTextStream has similar behavior with QIODevice::Text flag, see discussion here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/12954